# How to create a new object from my existent object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I create a new object from my other object please? So I have this code:

```
var test = {
    p1: [
        'factorial',
        '11'
    ],
    p3: 'temp1',
    x1: 'factorial'
};
```

and I want to get this:

```
Newobj = {
    factorial: [
        'p1',
        'x1'
    ],
    11: 'p1',
    temp1: 'p3'
}
```

To explain more: the values from the first object will be the keys in the second, but as you see there is an array, I need to go through all the values. Plus, I don't want to get a repeated one. For example, factorial exists in two keys : p1 and x1 so factorial needs to be written only once but with an array containing from where we got it.

Thank you!!

Comment: You may find the methods `Object.prototype.keys` and `Array.prototype.reduce` helpful.

Comment: It's not clear _how_ you wish to construct the second object from the first. How do the keys and values from the first object relate to the second?

Comment: @phil maybe she's switching out the key value pairs?

Comment: @C.Champagne not even close

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense I think I understand what OP wants to do (ie, I'm making some assumptions) but the question could do with some proper explanation

Comment: @Phil maybe this question isn't real. 1 rep, 1 question, 1 line explanation.

Comment: Looks like OP wants to turn all values (be they singular or an array) into keys and add each key with that value to the new key's value

Comment: @Phil So the values from the first object will be the keys in the second, but as you see there is an array, I need to go through all the values. Plus, I don't want to get a repeated one. For example, factorial exists in two keys : p1 and x1 so factorial needs to be written only once but with an array containing from where we got it

Comment: @AmiraSaid add details to your question by editing it. The comments section is not the place. Also, what have you tried so far? What is / isn't working?

Comment: @Phil I don't know how to go through an array that contains another array because Object.values gives me an array with my values, but the thing is that some values can contain arrays as well. I mean how to go through the whole values without repeating any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just a sucker for these map/reduce problems.

I would first create a *map* of `test` *value* to an array of `test` *keys* matching that value.

Then reduce that *map* to a plain object, taking the array value if its length is greater than one, otherwise just the first entry.

```js
const test = {"p1":["factorial","11"],"p3":"temp1","x1":"factorial"}

// create an intermediary Map of keys and values
const newMap = Object.keys(test).reduce((map, key) => {
  // force the value to an array for consistency and iterate
  [].concat(test[key]).forEach(val => {
    // create or add to the "key" to the array at map.get(val)
    map.set(val, (map.get(val) || []).concat(key))
  })
  return map
}, new Map())

// now reduce the Map entries to a plain object
const newObj = Array.from(newMap).reduce((obj, [key, val]) => ({
  ...obj,
  [key]: val.length > 1 ? val : val[0] // only use an array if more than one entry
}), Object.create(null)) // Object.create(null) creates a plain object

console.info(newObj)
```

Some advice though... I would make all the values arrays, even if there's only one entry. This create a consistent API for iterating and consuming your object.